# Young Adult book from 80's or 90's: unpopular girl finds a vampire in her attic

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, horror

I'm trying to remember the name of a book I read as a teenager. It's about an unpopular girl who finds a vampire in her attic. She makes a deal with the vampire to become popular in return for feeding the vampire other students at her school.

Comment: Are you sure it's not Twilight? =P

Answer (score 4):

*The Vampire's Promise* (1993) by Caroline Cooney, from the *[Point Horror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_Horror#1993)* series.

> A vampire lives in the tower of the creepy old house in town—a vampire who makes promises and grants wishes. Few know he exists. When Althea, Devnee, and Lacey meet the vampire, he offers them the things they want most—popularity, beauty, freedom.
>
> But his bargains come for a price.
>
> How much are the girls willing to pay? How many lives will they destroy? And is there any way out of a vampire's promise?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but I found the books. They're on Kindle if you haven't found them yet.

*The Vampire's Promise* trilogy by Caroline Cooney. Here is the first book's (*Deadly Offer*) summary from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/479325.Deadly_Offer):

> When you make a deal with a vampire, there's no chance to change your mind. Or is there?
>
> Althea is a nobody who wants to be somebody. She wants to be noticed, to have friends, to be part of the popular crowd. Then she meets the vampire who lives in the circular tower in her new house.

The vampire says that he can make her popular--more popular than she ever imagined she could be. All Althea has to do is agree to a simple deal. So simple a promise, but so evil.

[image: Three books covers]

Comment: Hi there! I've added a summary but could you maybe [edit] in the parts that make you think this is the one? (especially since these books were apparently published in early 2000's, which is later than what the question asked for)

Comment: I don't feel like this really are much to the same answer made 5 years ago.

Answer (score -2):

I know exactly the book that OP is talking about!
I was googling the plot to try and find the name.

As far as I can tell, The Vampire's Promises is the name of the trilogy and OP is specifically talking about the first book which has two names ("[Deadly Offer](http://www.carolinebcooneybooks.com/books/bk_deadlyoffer.html)" and "The Cheerleader").

Will see if I can find it and re=read it to confirm.

Comment: This basically just replicates the information from the prior answer. Unless you have something substantive to add, I'd advise editing the existing answer.